# github-pages: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '*\next\build'

Tags: github, next.js, github-pages

I want to deploy my Next.js project on GitHub and installed `gh-pages` to my Next.js project, based on https://blog.logrocket.com/8-ways-deploy-react-app-free/#github-pages, using

```bash
npm install --save gh-pages
```

But after

```bash
npm run deploy
```

the project successfully built, but using these two commands

```bash
breeze-next@0.1.0 deploy
gh-pages -d build
```

this error came up:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'project-path\breeze-next\build'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you are using Next.js and trying to deploy your application to GitHub Pages using the gh-pages package. By default, the gh-pages package looks for a "build" folder in the root of your project, but since Next.js uses a different folder name for the build output (".next" by default), you need to specify the custom build directory to use with gh-pages.

To do this, you can add a "distDir" configuration to your Next.js project's "next.config.js" file. This will tell Next.js to use a different directory for the build output. In your case, you can set it to "build" to match the default directory that gh-pages looks for.

**Here is an example of what your "next.config.js" file might look like:**

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  distDir: 'build',
}
```

**NOTE!**

**but GitHub Pages provides a simple way to deploy a Next.js application to a GitHub Pages site using GitHub Actions.

**Here are the steps you can follow:**

1. Go to the repository where your Next.js application is located.
2. Click on the "Settings" tab.
3. In the left column, select the "Pages" tab.
4. Under the "Source" section, select "GitHub Actions".
5. Click on the "Save" button.
6. GitHub will automatically create a workflow file for you. You don't need to
   make any changes to this file, so you can just commit it to your
   repository.
7. Wait for the build and deployment process to complete. This may take a few
   minutes.
8. Once the deployment is complete, you should be able to see your Next.js
   application hosted on the GitHub Pages URL.

Using this method, you don't need to install any additional packages or configure any settings in your Next.js project. GitHub Pages will take care of building and deploying your application for you.